# Copying the Numbers detected by OCR

Tags: pi-3, bash

Heyo,

Im working on a project with a Raspberry pi3, and i got an OCR working. Im using ssocr https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~auerswal/ssocr/ and it is detecting the Numbers on my pictures correctly.

What I want to know is how can I write a Bash script, so it automaticly Copy and pastes the number into a VPN program. (The numbers get output in the Terminal).

I tried googling about this, maybe i was using the wrong keywords but i couldnt find anything about this.

Comment: You should explain what the program you are using does in terms of output and not implicitly expect people to go read the link.  E.g, is it a commandline program that outputs numbers to a terminal?  Edit this explanation into the question, do not put it here in comments.

Comment: Does it have to use a VPN? Why not just make a server for the RPi to call?

Comment: Yes, it does have to use a VPN. Thats what i got told.

Comment: you got told by who?

Comment: Im doign a workers placement, and they just gave me this task for 4 weeks to do, im basicly supposed to google everything  / find out myself, even tho i had no experience with the basics of programming/VPn's etc.

Answer (score 1):

VPN is a virtual private network and safely connects two networks mainly over the ethernet. It builds a so called VPN tunnel. You can copy data through this tunnel to the other side into a program there. But this program isn't a `VPN program`. It can be any program. I suggest you split your issue into two problems: first transfer the console output (numbers) from your source program into the destination program and when it works, copy it through the VPN tunnel to the destination program on the other side. I will focus on the first step here. There are many ways to transfer data from on program to another with bash. Your information is very vague but I will give you some common ways to give you an idea how it could work. With your comments we are maybe able to specify your problem. But by the way, this isn't really a Raspberry Pi specific problem.

If your `destprog` is working as filter you can simply pipe data to it:

```
rpi ~$ srcprog | destprog
```

If your `destprog` can read from a file you can redirect the output from `srcprog` to a file and read that:

```
rpi ~$ srcprog > /tmp/srcprog.out
rpi ~$ destprog /tmp/srcprog.out   # read from file
rpi ~$ rm /tmp/srcprog.out
```